# Issues on Blazor Update

Tags: blazor

I have downloaded the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DevServer to 3.0.0-preview9.19465.2 and downloaded the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient to 3.0.0-preview9.19465.2

Updated the packages that has to be updated both on the client and server. Then removed the unnecessary things. Then built my solution. I can build successfully, but when I run the project I get stuck on the Loading... and in my inspector I get this error:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router' does not have a property matching the name 'ChildContent'.
```

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the default App.razor in a new project - it will be very different to your upgraded one. They changed the routing drastically

Answer (score 1):

Check out your app.razor file and change it to the following

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Also go into _Imports.razor and make sure there are no issues resolving any of the using statements. For example, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Layouts no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem..

I upgraded from '3.0.0-preview6.19307.2' to '3.0.0-preview9.19465.2' and upgraded a single preview at a time, and used the following links to cover everything they upgraded in each version..

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-7/
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-8/
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/

I then updated my App.razor with the following

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Hope this helps!